# do while statement executing only twice code::block and dev c++

Tags: c, while-loop, codeblocks, dev-c++, getchar

Hi guys attached is the code i am using a simple one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{char choice;
    do
    {
        printf("\nHello World");
        printf("\nDo you wish to continue:\n");
        choice = getchar();
    }
    while(choice=='y');
}
```

On Execution i get the following output:

```
Hello World
Do you wish to continue
y

Hello World
Do you wish to continue
--------------------End of Program--------------------
```

As you would notice,
The getchar() function did not work on the second iteration.
More so, the program did not wait for me to enter the input 'choice' on the second iteration.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Adding to what others have said, `c` should be an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The "Enter" key which you will press after the first input stays in the buffer and is read the next time control reaches to `getchar()`.
To avoid it you can just use another `getchar()` just after your first one, which will absorb the newline character entered. Or you can use this

`if(c != '\n')
    c=getchar();`

Answer (score 1):

After entering `y` you are pressing `enter` key which is taken as second input.So the program terminates as the second choice is not `y` but its `\n`..you can use this

```
do
{
    printf("\nHello World");
    printf("\nDo you wish to continue:\n");
    choice = getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

the second getchar() takes `\n` automatically as input and skips it

Answer (score 0):

You press 'enter' after y and then, for next getchar(), enter is taken as the input. You can either flush or use two getchar s and consider only the first input
ex: c=getchar();
    d=getchar();

check for c in while